# Do I need to specify HTML options that are "default" according to W3Schools?

Tags: html, dir

Do I need to specify HTML options that are "default" according to W3Schools?

I have always thought that you could omit "default" HTML options such as `dir="ltr"` in `<html>`, or `media="all"` in `<link>` for stylesheets.

But I frequently see big websites (e.g. YouTube) do this anyway. Is there any advantage by doing this, or are they only wasting a few bytes?

I have been wondering this for quite some time, and I was thinking that there might be browsers that handle things differently, such as displaying web pages in RTL by default.

Comment: Use caution when using W3Schools as reference: http://w3fools.com/

Comment: w3schools is [**not a reliable resource**](http://w3fools.com/). Use something such as MDN or the W3.org standards instead.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Thanks. I was not aware of this, but I have yet to find a good alternative. Unfortunately both MDN and W3 do not provide similar information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not pay any attention to what W3schools says about defaults.

There are many default attribute values in HTML, and in those cases, you need not specify the attribute if you want to get the default; that’s the very point of defaults. You may do so, for explicitness or some other reason (like styling or scripting).

But the `dir` attribute has no default value set in HTML specifications. In practice, browsers mostly default to `dir=ltr`, but this is not required. (The prose of HTML 4.01 just mentions the two values. The DTDs specify no default value.) In HTML5 drafts, however, it seems that the default for `dir` on the root element would be set to `ltr`.

The default for `media` in `link` is set to `screen` in the HTML 4.01. There are some inconsistencies here, and browsers may in fact imply `all`. So it is quite understandable that people wish to make it explicit whether a style sheet should apply to screen only or to all media.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you might decide to if you find a browser that messes things up otherwise.

YouTube probably does it because they have styling for ltr and rtl, so they can use a selector such as `html[dir='ltr']` in their CSS.

Also, you'll likely get people commenting saying w3schools is an unreliable resource, which it often is, so be careful of the information you learn from there.

Comment: Why would they not style for _ltr_ and use such selectors for _rtl_ in CSS? I have also checked their CSS, and both _dir_ and _direction_ are not mentioned.